# For an entire function $|f(z)| \le \sup_{\xi \in \partial D} |f(\xi)|$ for all $z \in D$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I was presented with a fact that for any entire function $f$ and any open disk $D$ it is true that $\forall z \in D$
$$
|f(z)| \le \sup_{\xi \in \partial D} |f(\xi)|.
$$

But why is it true? Maybe it is a theorem that has a particular name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).